# WP_Query order by multiple custom meta keys & fields

Tags: wordpress

How to order query by multiple meta keys combine with fields like title?

For example, this order by only 1 meta key and 1 field:

```
$args = array
    (
        'post_type' => 'listing',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num title',
        'meta_key' => 'listing_status',
        'order' => 'ASC',
    );

$royal_listings = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I want to order by multiple meta keys and multiple fields and set custom ASC/DESC order to each meta key/field.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/246355/order-by-multiple-meta-key-and-meta-value

Comment: @CBroe its not order by...

Comment: Still trivial to research (once you make an actual effort, which it doesn’t look like so far) ... https://www.billerickson.net/wp-query-sort-by-meta/

Comment: And even https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters has an example already (section titled “'orderby' with multiple 'meta_key's”)

Comment: I hope you understand my question.

Comment: No, if the multiple and easy to find places that explain how to sort a query result by more than one meta field still did not answer your question yet ... then you might need to make it more clear.

Comment: There is no solution for ordering by multiply meta keys in your two links. There is solution to order by multiple **fields**, which different from **meta keys**.

Comment: [Please see here my code](http://index1.s217.upress.link/code.txt)

Comment: _“There is no solution for ordering by multiply meta keys in your two links”_ - so then the section title `'orderby' with multiple 'meta_key's` must be referring to something completely different then …?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

Comment: Ok, got it. Section 'orderby' with multiple 'meta_key's.